# Android M - How to detect when system settings are being displayed (Foreground activity)

Tags: android

In there any way to detect when the user access the `System.settings` activity for Android M?

Since **getRunningTasks() is deprecated**, i've tried to use this lib:
https://github.com/jaredrummler/AndroidProcesses, but the settings doesn't appear on the returned list of processes.

Thanks!

Comment: Beyond that, I am reasonably certain that the library in question will not work on Android N. That code relies on reading the contents of `/proc`, which is no longer supported. Apps finding out what other apps are in the foreground has significant security and privacy concerns. Plus, with multi-window, "foreground" gets complicated. I would strongly recommend that you re-engineer your app to not care what other apps are in the foreground.

Comment: Thank you @CommonsWare, i will follow your advice and change the way it's currently done. I have an option on my app to block the settings access on demo devices and was using the name of the settings process to detect when the settings activity was displayed. Do you have any ideia how to do it without using the process name?

Comment: Use kiosk mode on Android 5.0+ devices.